# My WordPress Plugin is not showing except admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am going to create a plugin for WordPress. If I activate it, it's showing when I logged in as 'Admin', but if I logged in as 'Editor' it's not showing.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'afaq_6310_animated_accordion_faq');

function afaq_6310_animated_accordion_faq()
{
   add_menu_page('Accordion FAQ', 'Accordion FAQ', 'custom_capability_name', 'afaq-6310-accordion-faq', 'afaq_6310_home', 'dashicons-id-alt', 100);
   add_submenu_page('afaq-6310-accordion-faq', 'Accordion FAQ', 'All Accordion FAQ', 'custom_capability_name', 'afaq-6310-accordion-faq', 'afaq_6310_home');
}
```

Comment: Please check [add_menu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) and [add_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) there is parameter for capability

Answer (score 0):

Use 'edit_posts' capability. Try the following code -

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'afaq_6310_animated_accordion_faq');

function afaq_6310_animated_accordion_faq(){
   add_menu_page('Accordion FAQ', 'Accordion FAQ', 'edit_posts', 'afaq-6310-accordion-faq', 'afaq_6310_home', 'dashicons-id-alt', 100);
   add_submenu_page('afaq-6310-accordion-faq', 'Accordion FAQ', 'All Accordion FAQ', 'edit_posts', 'afaq-6310-accordion-faq', 'afaq_6310_home');
}
```